# Getting error - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined - in IONIC Native Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have integrated the Google Map in my Ionic 3 app and it was working perfectly, but after some time it stopped working. It gives me error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`.

[image]
So I've uninstalled the Ionic Native Google Maps plugin and again installed as suggested [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/README.md).

But when I installed it, it gave me an error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` for ionic native core and it's crashed my app. So I've again downgraded ionic native core plugin to `4.18.0` (the latest one is v. 5.10.0), and the application started work again, but my google map still not working.

My code for google maps is as below.

```
import {
   GoogleMaps,
   GoogleMap,
   GoogleMapsEvent,
   GoogleMapOptions,
   CameraPosition,
   MarkerOptions,
   Marker,
   Environment
 } from "@ionic-native/google-maps";
 export class MapPage {
   map: GoogleMap;
   constructor() {
   }
   ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.loadMap();
   }
   loadMap() {
      //https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/markeroptions/README.md'
      // This code is necessary for browser
      Environment.setEnv({
           API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE: "<MY_KEY>",
           API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG: "<MY_KEY>"
      });

      let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
          target: {
            lat: 25.284538,
            lng: 51.511393
          },
          zoom: 13,
          tilt: 30
         }
       };

  this.map = GoogleMaps.create("map_canvas", mapOptions);
  this.getMarkers();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem, also have to downgrade the native core, I just downgrade the maps plugin to 4.21.0 with

```
npm install @ionic-native/google-maps@4.21.0
```

This version still has support for the Ionic 3 core

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I've used javascript SDK for a google map but will try it though